# Find in files with VS Code extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm implementing a vs code extension that utilizes the [Tree View](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/tree-view-sample).

Whenever user clicks on the item, I'd like to perform a "find in files" command.

```
public getTreeItem(element: Item): TreeItem {
    return {
        label: element.name,
        collapsibleState: element.isGroup ? TreeItemCollapsibleState.Collapsed : TreeItemCollapsibleState.None,
        command: element.isGroup ? void 0 : {
            command: 'workbench.action.findInFiles',
            arguments: [element.name],
            title: 'Find references'
        }
     ...
   }
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing `element.name` as an argument for `workbench.action.findInFiles` command. 
Doesn't work - it simply opens the Search sidebar.

I looked for some reference in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands) but with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

[As of the April 2019 release (1.34)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/71626), this is now possible by specifying the `query` argument. You can also use `triggerSearch` to start the search immediately:

```
{
    command: 'workbench.action.findInFiles',
    arguments: {
        query: element.name,
        triggerSearch: true
    },
    title: 'Find references'
}
```

The full list of options is as follows:

```
export interface IFindInFilesArgs {
    query?: string;
    replace?: string;
    triggerSearch?: boolean;
    filesToInclude?: string;
    filesToExclude?: string;
    isRegex?: boolean;
    isCaseSensitive?: boolean;
    matchWholeWord?: boolean;
}
```

Note that `query` must be set for any of the other values to be respected.